# executing c# console application from python script - good design?

Tags: c#, python, json, console

**Could you please share your thoughts on whether this is good design, and which platforms would be more suitable for such functionality**:

1. Python script serves a static page
2. User sends post, which Python uses to call a C# console application
3. C# console app takes commands via stdin, talks to a SOAP web-service, and returns json
4. Python parses json and returns results to the user

It actually works (I am pleasantly surprised), but is this the best way to do things? Is there another nice alternative? A better way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why this mix of Python and C#? Each of these languages can do the whole job, so why not just choose one and use it for everything?

Comment: C# can do the whole job? Do people write simple fast web-servers on c#? I'm using gevent at the moment - seems to work greatly for the task.That's my question, really.

Comment: If so, why not do the SOAP and JSON part in Python?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I have tried it a number of times, but didn't succeed in generating correct classes from WSDL - it works fine with simple calls, but when you get to process complex sets of data, everything falls apart. So I had to resort to bare HTTP (creating and parsing envelopes manually), which wasn't nice. It's very simple in c# though. Is Python the wrong tool then? What else do people use in such scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot find good enough SOAP libs for Python (did you try `suds`?) and cannot add a JSON (or something else) counterpart to the SOAP web service then there may be no better way to do this but this still doesn't make the design good. Some problems just don;t have a good answer unless you are ready to write the missing parts yourself.